# How to go back to the original view using pop view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a button & when i click on button it moves to another view controller then there is a back button when i click on that it takes time to go back

I am doing it like this

```
GeoNewsViewController*targetController=[[GeoNewsViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    //remove unnecessary code here if u have

    //if u use any webservice then cancel connection here

    //stop any animations if

}
```

You can programatically go back with animation like this

```
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```